# Finding the CDF of a a sequence of independent random variables

Tags: time-series, stationarity, cumulative-distribution-function

Let $Z_t$, where $t$ is even, be a sequence of independent random variables defined as,
$$Z_t = \left\{\begin{array}{ccc} +1 & , & p = \frac{1}{2} \\ -1 & , & p = \frac{1}{2}\end{array}\right.$$

and $Z_t = Z_{t - 1}$ if $t$ is odd.

I need to show that the process $Z_t$ is first-order stationary in distribution, which seems straight forward from the definition, however I am confused on how to find the CDF based on the PMF $Z_t$.

Comment: Have you tried computing $P(Z_t\leq x)$ for any given $x$? There's not that many cases to consider.

Comment: Though even that is hardly necessary: when $t$ is even all $Z_t$ are identically distributed, and this identical distribution extends to when $t$ is odd.  Though the process is clearly not second-order stationary

Comment: The joint PMF can take one of four values: $(-1, -1)$, $(-1, 1)$, $(1, -1)$, $(1, 1)$, each with a probability of $\frac{1}{4}$. Since the joint PMF is the same in any case, wouldn't this make $Z_t$ second-order stationary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CDF of a single value is pretty straightforward here:

$$F_{Z_t}(z) = \mathbb{P}(Z_t \leqslant z) = \frac{1}{2} \bigg[ \mathbb{I}(z \geqslant -1) + \mathbb{I}(z \geqslant 1) \bigg].$$

Since this does not depend on $t$, the process is [first-order stationary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_process#Nth-order_stationarity).  As pointed out in the comments, the process is first-order stationary but not second-order stationary.